# Active Record OR query in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to find user id in 2 columns of Event object so need to use OR query.
What is the correct way to do it?
The code below doesn't work.

```
@event=Event.where((user_id= (current_user.id)) or (user2_id= current_user.id))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write as

```
@event = Event.where("user_id = :uid or user2_id = :uid", {uid: current_user.id})
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use like

```
@event=Event.where("user_id= ? or user2_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to have a better database structure, so you don't use need to use `user#{N}_id` to find users.

Presumably, I would split the table you have into two, where each table has `user_id`. You can paste some code, so I can help you with that.

The second point, it seems that model operations are currently done in Controller, you might want to move Business logic into the model.

Answering your question, you can do:

```
  current_user_id = current_user.id
  query = "select * from events where user_id = #{current_user_id} or user2_id = #{current_user_id}"
  result = Event.connection.execute(query)
```

Source:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/connection

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming for Rails 5 you can use `OR` as documented [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or)

```
Post.where("id = 1").or(Post.where("id = 2"))
# SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts`  WHERE (('id = 1' OR 'id = 2'))
```

You don't need to wait for rails 5 to use this `OR` query. We can also used it with `rails 4.2`, thanks to  gem [where-or](https://github.com/Eric-Guo/where-or)